# Rotating arrow issue

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

So I have a FAQ thingy that I made. Everything is working nicely, except I would like the ion icon to rotate 90 degrees when I click on the specific list element. Here is one of the 6 HTML blocks I have

```
<li class = "q"><i class = "ion-arrow-down-a"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,kdfssdfksdfkdfskfsdkfdskfdskkfdskfdskdsf</li>

 <li class = "a">blahfshfshbshhaj JFDSJSDFJFSDJFSDJFSDJFJDSJFSDJFSDJFDJFDJFSDJ</li>
```

I have about 6 more of these. Now my jQuery is where the real issue lies at. Everything up to the `slideUp();` portion is working fine. But the ion icon isn't rotating at all.

```
var action = "click";
var speed = 500;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.q').on(action,function(){
        $(this).next()
            .slideToggle(speed).
            siblings('li.a').
        slideUp();
    var i = $(this).children('i');
    $('i').not(i).removeClass('rotate');
    i.toggleClass('rotate');
    });
});
```

In my CSS I have also made a rotate class

```
.rotate
{
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reason

Contrary to what was originally mentioned in the other answer, the problem is ***not because the class is added to the*** `i` element. Instead ***it is because of the*** `display` ***setting of the elements***.

CSS `transform` ***does not work on inline elements***. They work only on elements whose display is block, inline-block, inline-table etc. Below is an extract from the [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element):

> **transformable element**
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform [SVG11].
>
> **atomic inline-level element**
>
> Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements) are called atomic inline-level boxes

By default ***most browsers set*** `i` ***element as*** `display: inline`. So, when the `transform` is applied to it (through the `rotate` class), it has no effect at all. That is, the element doesn't rotate (and so, the pseudo-element also remains un-rotated).

It works when you directly set the `transform` to `rotate:before` because all pseudo-elements have their `display` set as `inline-block` by most browsers.

---

#### Solution

***Change the*** `display` ***of*** `i` ***element to be*** `inline-block`. This would mean that the rotate transform would actually have an effect.

When you add a `transform` to an element all its child elements (which includes pseudo-elements) will be affected by the transform and so there is no need to set the class to the pseudo-element.

```js
var action = "click";
var speed = 500;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li.q').on(action, function() {
    $(this).next()
      .slideToggle(speed).
    siblings('li.a').
    slideUp();
    var i = $(this).children('i');
    $('i').not(i).removeClass('rotate');
    i.toggleClass('rotate');
  });
});
```

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* add this setting */

i {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="q"><i class="ion-arrow-down-a"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,kdfssdfksdfkdfskfsdkfdskfdskkfdskfdskdsf</li>

<li class="a">blahfshfshbshhaj JFDSJSDFJFSDJFSDJFSDJFJDSJFSDJFSDJFDJFDJFSDJ</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

as Harry mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37638933/6394256), the main reason is the display setting of the i element.so adding the transform to the pseudo-element is another option for doing this.

if you look into `ionicons.css` the css for `ion-arrow-down-a` class is:

```
.ion-arrow-down-a:before { content: "\f103"; }
```

::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the element matched. pseudo-elements are added to selectors but instead of describing a special state, they allow you to style certain parts of a document. For example, the ::first-line pseudo-element targets only  the first line of an element specified by the selector.
therefor according to ionicon.css you can use :before after the class name for transformation as well.

you can change your class like this:

```
.rotate:before
{
   transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

or add this css style:

```
i {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

working samlple [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/2onsxLLt/1/)

Comment: Why must I add before? Not understanding the logic behind this

Comment: @Munt If it helps you to grasp it, try using a more specific selector such as `.rotate.ion-arrow-down-a:before`. As @hsh mentions, the icon is actually rendered to the screen as a pseudo-element with that `:before` style rule.  The pseudo-element is distinct from the `<i>` element.  What you need to rotate is the pseudo-element created by the `:before`.

Comment: @SimianAngel: The solution to add the transform to the pseudo-element is not wrong (it is one possible solution) but the explanations are wrong. When the transform is added to a parent, its children are affected by default. The real reason why it doesn't work in this case is because the `i` is an inline element which is not a transformable element as per spec.